# Binding getter array to checkbox group

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a two page form so I am trying to mix submitting data to the server as well as making use of vuex.  So on page one, I have a simple form which contains a group of checkboxes (removed layout and styling to reduce code)

```
<b-form @submit.stop.prevent="onSubmit">
    <b-form-group>
        <input v-model="$v.form.checkboxGroup.$model" type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="1">
        <input v-model="$v.form.checkboxGroup.$model" type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" value="2">
        <input v-model="$v.form.checkboxGroup.$model" type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" value="3">
    </b-form-group>

    <button class="btn try-btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
</b-form>
```

Essentially, when submitted, I send the form data to my repository so it can be saved on the backend.  If this is successful, I call the following method

```
handleSubmitSuccess (response) {
  if (response.data.action === 'next_step') {
    this.$store.dispatch('createCheckboxData', this.$v.form.$model)
    return
  }
}
```

This method sets the checkbox data in my store and routes the user to the next page (removed this part).  So all of this is fine, seems to work well.

So when on page two, I have a button that can take you back to page one.  My idea is that if this happens, I use the previously checked data in the store to auto check the previously selected checkbox.  As such, on page one I added a computed method

```
computed: {
    checkboxData () {
      return this.$store.getters.checkboxData
    }
}
```

Now if I output checkboxData to the console, it seems to be an Observer object

```
[{…}, __ob__: Observer]
  0:
    checkboxData: Array(2)
      0: "1"
      1: "3"
      length: 2
```

So the above shows that previously, the first and second checkboxes were checked.

My question is how can I now use this data to auto-check my checkboxes.  I have seen some examples online, but they do not seem to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The way you use Vue is a little different to me so you might have to change this but, basically, you can set your `v-model` to whatever array is set in the Vuex store and it will set those checkboxes to true:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    checkbox: [],
    vuexData: ['1', '3']
  },
  mounted() {
    this.checkbox = this.vuexData;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="1">
  <input v-model="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" value="2">
  <input v-model="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" value="3">
  {{ checkbox }}
</div>
```